# vlc streaming over the network (delay reduce)

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, cache, delay

My name is yeonho choi, I'm Korean. I am network streaming Desktop(Display) and Desktop(Display) over RTP, when I view the stream (even on the same machine) there is a delay of about 1.2 seconds. I have tried setting the RTP cache setting to 0, or 1 but it doesn't seem to help.

Please you have any ideas how I could reduce the delay, to something better suited to for a conference < 1 second?

```
sprintf(chTemp2, "#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=800,fps=30,scale=1,acodec=mp4a, ab=128, channels=2, samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=display{delay=1000}:dst=rtp{dst=192.168.0.183,port=5004,mux=ts,ttl=12},dst=file{dst=D:\\\\VIDEO\\\\%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d.avi,no-overwrite}}",Time.nYear,Time.nMonth,Time.nDay,Time.nHour,Time.nMin,Time.nSec); //모니터 화면 스트림 output + 파일저장

const char* chOption[]={"screen-top=200", "screen-left=100","screen-width=800","screen-height=400","screen-fps=15","live-caching=300"};

vlcPlayer_.AddBroadCast("", chTemp1, chTemp2, 6, chOption, 1, 0); 
vlcPlayer_.PlayBroadCast("");
```